# For loop without counter for NSDates

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I would like increment a date until it reaches the current date.  I want it to increment  one week at a time so if the date starts at two weeks ago Wednesday at 3 or last week, Wednesday at 3, it will increment to *next* Wednesday at 3 and stop.

Most for loops I am familiar with use counters ie `for (i=0;i<10;i++)` but this does not lend itself to a counter.  How would I do something like the following?

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate *date];
NSDate *newStartDate;

for (newStartDate<now) {
//increment date
}
```

Comment: why can't u use while instead of for loop?

Comment: That may be answer.  Trying it now

Comment: Yes, that was it.  Forgot about while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// While the new date/time comes before the current date/time
while ([now compare:newStartDate] != NSOrderedDescending) {
    // Add one week's worth of seconds to the new start date
    newStartDate = [newStartDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:7 * 24 * 60 * 60];
}
```

Comment: Pls edit answer for proper formatting and explanation.

Comment: It's fine as-is. There's no such thing as "proper formatting" and it contains more explanation than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

the < operator will only check the pointer value and not the dates

```
while([startDate earlierDate:stopDate] == startDate) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: or using `compare` and `NSOrderedAscending`. It should probably ignore time anyway.